# I want to set datasource of rdlc report with model in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, rdlc

here we bind Datatable. how to bind model instead of datatable??

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DsMemberWiseFine", dtMemberWiseFine));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need

1. create your own custom data using List
2. create a report using rdlc based on Custom data

Im not good at explaining, but you can visit this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports 
It will gives you a full explanation, codes and step by step procedures.

because I also experienced your problem, and that link solved it

Comment: ahh ok hahhaha. sorry for me.but I thought you can mark it as answer even you have a low points. but thanks to appreciate my answer